# Is it possible to install drivers on windows 10 to go and run it on multiple computers

Tags: drivers, windows-to-go

Is there any Problem if I installed drivers from "windows update" or any third party
programs on windows to go and than run it on multiple computers?

Comment: Super vague question is super vague. Do you want some mechanism to automatically roll out an application onto multiple machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows To-Go uses an external drive and restricts access to local disks.

All you will do is install drivers on this external harddrive. It should not cause for any conflicts, and if it does, these cases are extremely rare.

In the worst case, you will not be able to use one part of hardware because the drivers conflict with already installed drivers that you use on another pc. Windows itself will load fine.

The computers itself are not affected. The entire idea behind Windows To-Go is that you can do this, so yes, it will work in 99% of the cases without a problem.

Comment: Worth pointing on that `Windows To Go` is designed to work on different hardware without a problem.  However, the traditional physical installation of Windows is not designed to be migrated, at least not without some considerable amount of work.  You will be unable to take your traditional installation of Windows, and boot to it, on different hardware without first doing some steps to prepare the installation for the migration.  If you want this capability you should use `Windows To Go`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer
 
Which I understand from your Answer, there will be no physical damage to the host computers, is this true?

Comment: Yes, this is true. You are carrying the windows install, so all it can do is damage that install. Access to the internal harddrive is not possible with Windows To-Go, so you cannot alter it either.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about "windows to go", but regular windows provides 2 utils for doing it.

1. pnputil -a
2. dism /image:c:\ /Add-driver /driver:c:\driver /recurse

Additional you can mount a wim file directly with dism and use the command line to inject drivers.  The wim can be a copy of a hard drive using the imagex utility or the wim file found on the installation media.

Windows updates can be applied in a similiar manner
You have to download them from microsoft in the **msu** format.

for /R "C:\Updates\" %i in (*.msu) do dism /image:c:\mountw8 /Add-Package /PackagePath:"%i"

Additional programs comprised of **msi** files can be injected.

However, if it is not bundled in an msi file it probably won't happen.